# Get Query String value in view in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am working on Codeigniter and i want to get value from Query String.
Suppose this is my url :http://localhost/Myapp/controller/method/6.

I  want to get this 6 in my view, without the use of controller. I have tried this code but it did not work. 
With the below controller i.e. `edit_started($c_id)` i reach goal view, but on the goal view there is a button on which i have called refresh_div() function on loading that div i get the moveable_elements called into the main view i.e. goal. My main url is `localhost/Myapplication/Controllername/edit_started(6)`
but on getting it with `$this->uri->segment(n)` it gives `show_data` i.e. the ajax one url not the original one that was `localhost/Myapplication/Controllername/edit_started(6)`.

> Controller:

```
  public function edit_started($c_id)
    {   
    $data['result']=$c_id;
    $this->load->view('goal',$data);
    }
```

> View:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      function refresh_div()
      { 

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/show_data",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data){

        $('#demo').html(data);

        } 
});
```

> dashboard.php

```
public function show_data() {

$this->load->model('login_database');
$data['query']=$this->login_database->get_all_topics();
$this->load->helper('url');
$filter_view=$this->load->view('moveable_elements', $data,TRUE);
echo json_encode($filter_view);

}
```

Now moveable_elements is the view where i want to get the query string.

Comment: Put more code. What is `var_dump($this->uri->segment(3))`?

Comment: @Tpojka: I have updated my question and code, because my code i too big i cannot post the whole post but posted as much as needed.

Comment: My question is what do you get if you place `var_dump($this->uri->segment(3))` in view file for example. Is that `false`, `error`, empty string or something else? Or even you can `var_dump($this->uri->segment_array())` in view file and check array of segments of request.

Comment: @Tpojka: i have checked it with var_dump($this->uri->segment(3)) output is boolean false, with vardump($this->uri->segment(2)) it is string 'show_data' (length=9)  show_data is the function i have called through ajax

Comment: In your asking, you mentioned general uri as `controller/method/6`. What would be specific uri needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101920/discussion-between-user3653474-and-tpojka).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(4);
```

or

```
echo $this->uri->segment(3);
```

without qoutes.

Comment: Thanks Ilan i have tried but it is returning blank value

Comment: I have updated my question and code, because my code i too big i cannot post the whole post but posted as much as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please use 4 instead of 3**
echo $this->uri->segment(4);
OR
Please don't use "method" in url. Use them in your controller method
http://localhost/Myapp/controller/6
For eg:
function function_name(){
$this->load->model('model_File_Name');
$Create an Array = $this->model_File_Name->function_name_created in model();
$this->load->view(view_file_name,$Array_Name);
}
```

Comment: Because i am using ajax to load a view i have to use it in view and in view it is not  working

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the line you are ooking for

```
$query_string_value = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());
```